# $_get and file_get_contents don't work together

Tags: php, get

I have a PHP script that basically tries to convert the string it gets from:

```
https://camwijs.nl/system/avatarimage.aspx?username=
```

to

```
https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=
```

If I run the code it just gives me an page with the error message:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https//camwijs.nl/system/avatarimage.aspx?username=nomakta): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u750368594/public_html/v1/avatar/avatar.php on line 4
>   http://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
// gets avatar with GR
$camwijsAvatarurl = "https//camwijs.nl/system/avatarimage.aspx?username=".htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]);
// displays avatar link here
 echo 'http://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?fgure=' .file_get_contents($camwijsAvatarurl);

?>
```

Comment: `. '';` you don't need to concatenate empty strings, just end it after file_get_contents() and htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra trailing `.` at the end of line 2, which throws a syntax error for improper concatenation:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in ... on line 2

Either remove that `.` or add `" "` (but only if you're planning on concatenating further)

Comment: Yes, this would fix that syntax error, but not the specific error that was put in the OP.  Maybe the OP has another issue in there (just not represented properly)

Comment: @Devon I'm inclined to agree. That error message implies that something above this line (or in an include?) is incorrect, probably missing a `;` or closing brace, something trailing, etc.

Comment: I fixed this error but now I have this error?

Warning: file_get_contents(https//camwijs.nl/system/avatarimage.aspx?username=nomakta): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u750368594/public_html/v1/avatar/avatar.php on line 4
http://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=

Comment: `Failed to open stream` is synonymous for `I can't find that`. You're missing `:` in `https//...` which may or may not be it. Double check your URL and make sure you can access it correctly.

Comment: That was an looking mistake But I'm now getting an HTTP REQUEST FAILED?
 >Warning: file_get_contents(http://camwijs.nl/system/avatarimage.aspx?username=nomakta): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /home/u750368594/public_html/v1/avatar/avatar.php on line 5
http://habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?fgure=

Comment: Ok, that means you don't have permission to access that page, as it's an `https`, **s** meaning secure. I don't know if I'll be able to help you with that one...

Comment: Just found out why this ISN'T possible. The owner of the website has cloudflare. He told me he was working on a version that directly makes the avatar. Thanks for the help anyways really appriciated